# Magento 2: After product collection join getting Allowed memory size exhausted error

Tags: magento2.3, product-collection, join-table

I am trying to join "catalog_category_product" table custom column to product collection like this,

```
public function beforeSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
    $collection
) {
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        ["catalog_category_product"],
        'e.entity_id = catalog_category_product.product_id AND catalog_category_product.category_id='.$this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory()->getId(),
        array('fig_id'))->Order('fig_id','ASC');
    
    //echo $collection->getSelect();exit;
    return [$collection];
}
```

[image: Query result returning correct values]

Query is returning correct output, but I am getting memory error on frontend category page.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /chroot/home/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 91
```

If anyone knows the answer please do share.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
`echo "<pre">;print_r($collection->getData());exit;`

Comment: As I mentioned, getting correct result with fig_id .  But on category page it's showing memory error.
Added screenshot of collection data in question.